# apache2.4 can't resolve virtual host configuration

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2

I'm setting up apache2.4 at example.org and we have 2 sites configured.

Site 1:

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost billingtest.example.org:443>
                ServerAdmin web@sad.asd
                ServerName billingtest.example.org

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.org.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.org.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/letsencrypt_sff_bundle.crt

                DocumentRoot /var/www/php/billing
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost billingtest.example.org:80>
        ServerAdminweb@sad.asd
        ServerName billingtest.example.org

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#       DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
        Redirect permanent / https://billingtest.example.org
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Site 2:

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost example.org:443>
                ServerAdmin web@sad.asd
                ServerName example.org

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.org.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.org.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/letsencrypt_sff_bundle.crt

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/main
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost example.org:80>
        ServerAdmin web@sad.asd
        ServerName example.org

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#       DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
        Redirect permanent / https://example.org
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When going to any of these sites I'm met with an index of the `/var/www/html` directory and if switch to the URL `server001.example.org` I get the same result.  `example.org` and `billingtest.example.org` are `CNAME` records of `server001.example.org` which is hosting the Apache server.

`example.org` (site 2) should be loading up a normal HTML website and `billingtest.example.org` (site 1) should be loading up a PHP site.

I'm not sure what's going on. I can supply my apache2.conf and logs. Also an error that got my attention was:

`(EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name billingtest.example.org -- ignoring!`

---

Thank you in advance for any support you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Moved reliance to ServerName instead of the vhost name. Swapped it back out to `_default_`. This only happens when using AWS, not Linode, I think it's because the machine doesn't use the public IP but runs through a firewall. This could be sorted w/ modifications to /etc/hosts which I wanted to avoid.

I'll just use `_default_`, thanks to Jim L. for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old(ish) question, but this might help someone else in a similar situation to me.

I got the same error as you (`Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name… -- ignoring!`) in `/var/log/messages/` happening during boot-up of the server.

Immediately after boot-up, Apache was ignoring the virtual host configuration – everything was pointing to the fall-back domain (and SSL certs weren't valid as a result). Strangely, restarting Apache with `systemctl restart httpd` fixed the problem.

So, it was only an issue immediately after a server reboot. The configs were fine, as shown by just restarting Apache! But I couldn't risk there being a reboot when I wasn't around to do that.

After much searching, I discovered that Apache was starting before the network was ready, and therefore it couldn't resolve the domain name, and so was ignoring it when setting up the virtual hosts.

So I did some searching, and it's fairly easy to tell systemd that Apache should wait until the network is up, during boot-up.

So, `systemctl edit httpd.service` brings up a text editor, into which I entered:

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

Save it, and now Apache waits until the network is properly up before starting.

For more detailed explanation about setting systemd startup order:

> https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/
>
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398540/how-to-override-systemd-unit-file-settings
>
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165270/centos-7-boots-too-fast-and-network-is-not-ready-when-executing-cron-scripts

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a clue.

> "Could not resolve ..."

means that the hostname `billingtest.example.org` doesn't exist in the DNS for `example.org`, or at least that the machine you refer to as `server001.example.org` cannot figure out what the IP number for `billingtest.example.org` is.

As for a solution to that, given that the name implies a test site, it may be that `billingtest.example.org` doesn't exist in the public DNS yet, precisely because it is a test site, and the name should not be published (yet).  That's great.  Add it to `/etc/hosts` on `server001`.  If its IP number is `10.11.12.13` then add this to `/etc/hosts`:

10.11.12.13        billingtest.example.org

Then restart Apache and see if that error message goes away.

That may seem like a hack, but IMO it's an excellent practice, because so long as you're testing, that URL is a "secret" name that doesn't **belong** in DNS.  Add it to `/etc/hosts` on the server, then add it also to `/etc/hosts` on **your** machine, and then you can hit that server with that name all day long, and no one else knows that the name is even in use (no DNS lookups, assuming your host consults `/etc/hosts` before DNS).

But if you trust a group of colleagues to keep a secret, you **can** add `billingtest.example.org` to your public DNS, and then anyone who possesses that URL can access the site.  When you're done testing, you can change the DNS record and the Apache config to just use `billing` instead of `billingtest`.

Adding the name to your public DNS should also fix the problem, although you'll have to wait for DNS propagation, and verify that `server001` can resolve `billingtest`, and restart Apache just as with the other method.

Comment: "It's an excellent practice" so long as you remember to take it **out** of `/etc/hosts` once the site goes live and the DNS kludge is no longer necessary.  :)

Comment: We're using Cloudflare, not sure if that will be an issue if we enable protection. Also, the record has propagated and it still isn't using the virtual hosts. Thanks for the help so far